# Expanded schemas with AJV

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

Is it possible to generate expanded/resolved schemas with AJV where `$ref` is used? `$ref` is extremely useful for keeping schemas DRY, but but not if you need an expanded representation of the schema.

When a schema is compiled, the returned function has the `schema` property, but that returns the non expanded schema that was supplied to the compile function in the first place. Further, there doesn't seem to be anything in the docs about it or even from a google search.

Is it possible to get an expanded schema where `$ref` is used?

Comment: What do you mean by "expanded / resolved schema"?

Comment: By expanded/resolved I mean that any `$ref` in a schema be replaced by the actual schema that is referencing.

Comment: @oorst There are several such tools. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-ref-parser is, I think, the most widely used.

Comment: Beware though, that they sometimes do not work quite correctly. If your schemas are mostly simple, you shouldn't run into any problem. It's more commonly known as dereferencing or more accurately "transclusion".

Answer (score 1):

While some tools provide some level of functionality to do this, it's not always possible to do this correctly, and sometimes impossible. `ajv` documents that it will not implement this functionality for reasons:

> 1. recursive $refs
> 2. List item $ref is not equivalent to the object inclusion,
>      because the $refs inside $ref should be resolved based on id in the
>      source schema and not based on id of the current schema.

https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/336#issuecomment-258538008